# Qt 5.1 with VS2012 compiler - code 128 error

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, qt-creator

I am trying to set up Qt 5.1 with MS Visual Studio 2012 compiler. I have downloaded and installed the VS Express (it works and compiles C++ code just fine) and then installed Qt.

Here is the console output from whenever I try to build anything:

```
09:07:14: Running steps for project cube...
09:07:14: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2012_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\examples\opengl\cube\cube.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2012 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
09:07:15: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2012_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
09:07:15: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
Usage: jom @commandfile
       jom [options] [/f makefile] [macro definitions] [targets]

nmake compatible options:
/A build all targets
/D display build information
/E override environment variable macros
/F <filename> use the specified makefile
/G display included makefiles
/H show help
/I ignore all exit codes
/K keep going - build unrelated targets on error
/N dry run - just print commands
/NOLOGO do not print logo
/P print makefile info
/R ignore predefined rules and macros
/S silent mode
/U print content of inline files
/L same as /NOLOGO
/W print the working directory before and after other processing
/X <filename> write stderr to file.
/Y disable batch mode inference rules

jom only options:
/DUMPGRAPH show the generated dependency graph
/DUMPGRAPHDOT dump dependency graph in dot format
/J <n> use up to n processes in parallel
/KEEPTEMPFILES keep all temporary files
/VERSION print version and exit
Error: unknown command line option '-' in arguments: '/L-IC:/QNX650/target/qnx6/usr/include'
09:07:15: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 128.
Error while building/deploying project cube (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2012 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
09:07:15: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Earlier I had the same problem with 5.0.2 (basically that's why I killed it and installed 5.1).

I couldn't Google anything reasonable regarding this kind of error. Looks like 128 propagates from somewhere within Visual Studio, but I can't figure out what it is.

Could anybody suggest how can I debug and fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You'll get a similar error if you set the `MAKEFLAGS` environmental variable in a way compatible with gnu make, for example `MAKEFLAGS=-j2` or `MAKEFLAGS=-j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`. gnu make on Windows does support parallel execution, just as jom does, only that the command line syntax differs (slash vs. dash).

Answer (score 2):

... And there's nothing that helps you figure out the problem better than writing it down and then starting at the post.

The "/L-IC:/QNX650/target/qnx6/usr/include" actually tells me that QNX SDK installed on my machine is messing with my environment variables. Luckily, Qt has a way of dealing with that. I need to go to Projects tab, expand the "build environment" section and unset the "MAKEFLAGS" environment variable. This fixes it.